# PHP Laravel, how to check if string date and time is not in the past

Tags: php, laravel

I want to check if date and time where stored in the session are not in the past and greater than 15 minutes of the current time

```
$time = Session::get('preorder_time');
$date = Session::get('preorder_date');
```

ex.

$date = "2020-08-15";

$time = "21:30";

I want to check if this time and date plus 15 minutes greater than current time

Comment: use carbon: if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date.' '.$time)->addMinutes(15)->gt(\Carbon\Carbon::now()){//your code}

Comment: very welcome :)), Shall I add it as an answer?

Comment: yes please I will make it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use carbon:

```
if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($date.' '.$time)->addMinutes(15)->gt(\Carbon\Carbon::now())
{
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all builtin date functions can parse that format, so:

```
$date = "2020-08-15";
$time = "21:30";
if (strtotime("$date $time") + 15*60 < time()) {
} else {
}
```

To inspect the value:

```
var_dump(date('r', strtotime("$date $time")));
```

```
string(31) "Sat, 15 Aug 2020 21:30:00 +0200"
```